# SQL returns result for an always false condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I'm confused on why the following SQL sentence returns one row:

```
#MySQL
select max(1) from dual where 0 = 1

#SQLite
select max(1) where 0 = 1
```

I'm really confused about this result. Can anyone please shed some light over this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An aggregate like `max` without a `group by` always returns one row.  If the underlying rowset it empty, it will return a single row with `null`.  Otherwise, it returns the maximum of the column you specified.

The `where` clause affects which rows the maximum is calculated for.  It does not change the fact that the query has to return a maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Because MAX is a scalar function so it needs to return a result, as opposed to a table-result query.

Answer (score 0):

It its returning the max value (or NULL in the case of no matching rows), so a single row returned seems logical

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't seem logical to me, this is why I'm asking :)